# How do i find 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Column M I have a range of numbers collected (positive and negative) however, I need to match them off against each other to find 0. Example:

```
-100
50
50
-200
75
25
100
```

Clearly here `-100+50+50=0` which I will match off against each other.

However, in my scenario I deal with a mix range of numbers. Is there a formula I can use to make it easier?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you stop at the second 50? If it is simply to find out which numbers from the top to the current row sum to zero then using SUM() for all your values above that cell will work.

Comment: what do you mean by match with each other, like +ve with -ve or the final result you want should 0 ? Since if  you SUM those numbers you get ZERO !!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have these numbers in A1 to A7 (this is probably an example, I just use this information to answer this question)

In B1 write: `=A1`

I would write in B2 to B7 the following formula: `=B1+A2` where 1 and 2 will go up by 1 depending on which row you are.

So B1: =B1+A2, B3: =B2+A3, and so on.

Column B will now have places where it says 0. Every cell from that to the previous 0 is a group.

The data would look something like this:

```
-100  -100 +
  50   -50 |
  50     0 +
-200  -200 +
  75  -125 |
  25  -100 |
 100     0 +
```

The line after the example is the group.

Comment: Should the user delete the none zero values (ie B1, B2, B4, B5 and B6) then this would effect the zero values. SUM() of the respective A columns would not be effected by deleting the none zero values in the B column.

Comment: Why would the user want to delete values in the debug column? The idea is that the user can find the groups quickly. It can then be marked in column A by selecting them and putting a border around it, then the entire column B can be removed. Sum() of entire A will not find individual groups.

Comment: SUM(A$1:AX) where X is your row number would work in the same way as your answer but would also continue to work should the values in your debug column be deleted.
As to why? No idea! But as it is a possibility which would effect the result I decided to comment. With this one change, your answer is identical to what I would do hence the comment instead of a new answer.

Comment: I see. Yeah, that would indeed work as well.